# Why request sending error Savon::SOAPFault: (ns1:SecurityError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap-client, savon

I am getting this error from the SOAP actions integration.
Savon::SOAPFault: (ns1:SecurityError) A security error was encountered when verifying the message

my Savon client look like this:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "https://212.154.167.194:9443/esf-web/ws/api1/SessionService?wsdl", 
        ssl_verify_mode: :none,
        env_namespace: :soapenv,
        pretty_print_xml: true,
        namespace_identifier: :nam, 
        env_namespace: :soapenv,
        namespaces: { "xmlns:nam" => "namespace.esf" },
        :raise_errors => true,
        log: true,
        #loglevel: :debug,
        pretty_print_xml: true)
        message = {
  "createSessionRequest" =>
  {
    "tin" => "placeholder",
    "x509Certificate" => "placeholder"
  }
}
```

and generated responce

```
response = client.call(:create_session, message: {:tin => 'XXXX', :x509Certificate => 'xxxxxx'})
```

The XML code should be here:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:esf="esf">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-664678CEF9FFC67AD214168421472821">
            <wsse:Username>123456789011</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>            
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <esf:createSessionRequest>
         <tin>?</tin>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <projectCode>?</projectCode>
         <x509Certificate>?</x509Certificate>
      </esf:createSessionRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In the xml you have the following username and password

```
<wsse:Username>123456789011</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
```

Where do you set those username and password?

[**Read the guide**](http://savonrb.com/version2/client.html) so that you can follow their steps to configure Savon:

```
response = client.call(:authenticate, message: { username: "luke", password: "secret" })
```